LWC loop through array and display content in html
I'm trying to display content of an array as I loop through it in HTML of an LWC.
js:
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAvailableProperties from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.getAvailableProperties';
import getAvailableBookingSlots from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.getAvailableBookingSlots';
import createBooking from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.createBooking';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class PropertyBooking extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedProperty;
    @track selectedSlot;
    @track error;
    @track slots = [];

    @wire(getAvailableProperties) properties;

    @wire(getAvailableBookingSlots, { propertyId: '$selectedProperty' })
    wiredSlots({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            //this.slots = data;
            for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                /* console.log('slot start ****  ', JSON.stringify(data[i].start));
                console.log('slot end ****  ', JSON.stringify(data[i].end)); */
                this.slots[i] = data[i].start + ' to ' + data[i].end;
            }
            console.log('this.slots ------- ', JSON.stringify(this.slots));
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.slots = [];
        }
    }

    get propertyOptions() {
        return this.properties.data ? this.properties.data.map(property => {
            return { label: property.Name, value: property.Id };
        }) : [];
    }

    handlePropertyChange(event) {
        this.selectedProperty = event.detail.value;
        this.selectedSlot = null; // Reset selected slot when changing property
    }

    handleSlotSelection(event) {
        this.selectedSlot = event.target.dataset.slot;
    }

    handleBooking() {
        if (this.selectedProperty && this.selectedSlot) {
            const slot = this.slots[parseInt(this.selectedSlot)];
            const startDate = new Date(slot.start);
            const endDate = new Date(slot.end);

            createBooking({ propertyId: this.selectedProperty, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate })
                .then(result => {
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Booking Status',
                            message: result,
                            variant: result.includes('successfully') ? 'success' : 'error',
                        })
                    );
                    if (result.includes('successfully')) {
                        // Refresh the available properties and slots
                        return refreshApex(this.properties) && refreshApex(this.wiredSlots);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error creating booking',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error',
                        })
                    );
                });
        } else {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Missing Information',
                    message: 'Please select a property and a date range to book.',
                    variant: 'warning',
                })
            );
        }
    }
}

Console looks like this:
this.slots -------  ["2024-06-08 to 2024-06-15","2024-06-15 to 2024-06-22","2024-06-22 to 2024-06-29","2024-06-29 to 2024-07-06","2024-07-06 to 2024-07-13","2024-07-13 to 2024-07-20","2024-07-20 to 2024-07-27","2024-07-27 to 2024-08-03","2024-08-03 to 2024-08-10","2024-08-31 to 2024-09-07","2024-09-07 to 2024-09-14","2024-09-14 to 2024-09-21","2024-09-21 to 2024-09-28","2024-09-28 to 2024-10-05","2025-06-08 to 2025-06-15","2025-06-15 to 2025-06-22","2025-06-22 to 2025-06-29","2025-06-29 to 2025-07-06","2025-07-06 to 2025-07-13","2025-07-13 to 2025-07-20","2025-07-20 to 2025-07-27","2025-07-27 to 2025-08-03","2025-08-03 to 2025-08-10","2025-08-10 to 2025-08-17","2025-08-17 to 2025-08-24","2025-08-24 to 2025-08-31","2025-08-31 to 2025-09-07","2025-09-07 to 2025-09-14","2025-09-14 to 2025-09-21","2025-09-21 to 2025-09-28","2025-09-28 to 2025-10-05"]

HTML for:each:
            <template for:each={slots} for:item="slot" for:index="index">
                {slot}
                <li key={slot} class="slds-m-bottom_xx-small">
                    <lightning-button
                        label='book'
                        onclick={handleSlotSelection}
                        data-slot={index}
                        class='slds-button_brand'>
                    </lightning-button>
                </li>
            </template>

I can't get the slot text to appear on the page.
Any suggestions appreciated.

where and how is slots declared?  Please edit your question to include this information.

@NickC - I added the JS file

I have tried your code in my org. I have set the static slot data and tried to render it into the HTML of LWC.
HTML:
<template>
      <template if:true={slots}>
            <ul>
                <template for:each={slots} for:item="slot" for:index="index">
                    <li key={slot} class="slds-m-bottom_xx-small">
                        {slot}
                        <lightning-button label="book" onclick={handleSlotSelection} data-slot={index}
                            class="slds-button_brand">
                        </lightning-button>
                    </li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>
            <p>{error}</p>
        </template>
</template>

JS:
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
export default class Test extends LightningElement {
    @track slots = ["2024-06-08 to 2024-06-15","2024-06-15 to 2024-06-22","2024-06-22 to 2024-06-29","2024-06-29 to 2024-07-06","2024-07-06 to 2024-07-13","2024-07-13 to 2024-07-20","2024-07-20 to 2024-07-27","2024-07-27 to 2024-08-03","2024-08-03 to 2024-08-10","2024-08-31 to 2024-09-07","2024-09-07 to 2024-09-14","2024-09-14 to 2024-09-21","2024-09-21 to 2024-09-28","2024-09-28 to 2024-10-05","2025-06-08 to 2025-06-15","2025-06-15 to 2025-06-22","2025-06-22 to 2025-06-29","2025-06-29 to 2025-07-06","2025-07-06 to 2025-07-13","2025-07-13 to 2025-07-20","2025-07-20 to 2025-07-27","2025-07-27 to 2025-08-03","2025-08-03 to 2025-08-10","2025-08-10 to 2025-08-17","2025-08-17 to 2025-08-24","2025-08-24 to 2025-08-31","2025-08-31 to 2025-09-07","2025-09-07 to 2025-09-14","2025-09-14 to 2025-09-21","2025-09-21 to 2025-09-28","2025-09-28 to 2025-10-05"];
    @track error;
}

Output:


Thanks @Tushar_Jadav - slots has a value and I still don't see it on the page. Could it have something to do with it being displayed in Experience Cloud?

When I hard-code slots, it shows on the page. I need to be able to get the slots from the backend though. What could be going on where I don't see it when I retrieve from code?

@mackmama, You need to give permission to the community User to access the LWC and Its Apex Controller. Also the Object and its fields.

Thanks - forgot about granting access to the custom objects. That did it.
